# BigTable aggregation data

Tags: database, google-bigquery, google-cloud-bigtable

I have been trying use BigTable with connector to BigQuery. And when I try test query performance from 1 million rows I got query speed result ~ 50sec.
My SQL:

```sql
    SELECT
            DATE(geo_table_cell.timestamp) AS day,
            geo_table_cell.value,
            COUNT(*) AS countNumber
        FROM
            `project-dev.project_dev_bt_eu.dev-project`,
            UNNEST(geo.COLUMN) AS geo_table,
            UNNEST(geo_table.cell) AS geo_table_cell
        WHERE
            geo_table.name = 'cc'
            AND rowkey LIKE 'profile%'
        GROUP BY
            geo_table_cell.value,
            DATE(geo_table_cell.timestamp)
```

My questions is:

1. What the best solution for aggregate data from BigTable? (The same aggregation from ElasticSearch takes less than  ~2 sec)
2. Why BigQuery works to slow with BigTable connector?
3. If I understand correct BigTable not good choice for present data to dashboards (filters work very slow);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.- In case query speed is a must, [loading the data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data) into BigQuery instead of setting up an external data source would be the most efficient way.
Nevertheless, there are some things you can do to improve [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-overview), or [BigTable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/performance) performances.

2.- This connector is still in the Beta stage, and has some [performance considerations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable#performance_considerations). We should also take into consideration that BigTable is a **noSQL** (non relational) database and is not intended for SQL queries.
In case you are exploring the data model you want to use in your application, I recommend you consider [all these options](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/overview#other-storage-options) and choose the one that fits better with your needs.

3.- I would say it is not a good choice if you want to query your data using SQL. Understanding de non relational architecture of BigTable, the most effective way to read your data would be sending [read requests](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reads).  You can find some code samples about this, in different languages in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reading-data).