# BigTable: Is there a better approach to get unique values from partial row keys?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I've made a bigtable with row key in `<name>#<date>#<id_value>`

and I'd like to get unique ids when I filter using row key prefix like below.

```
client = bigtable.Client(project=project_id, admin=True)
instance = client.instance(instance_id)
table = instance.table(table_id)
prefix = "phone#20190501"
end_key = prefix[:-1] + chr(ord(prefix[-1]) + 1)

# example row keys = ['phone#20190501#<id_value>', 'phone#20190501#<id_value>'...]

row_set = RowSet()
row_set.add_row_range_from_keys(prefix.encode("utf-8"),
                                end_key.encode("utf-8"))

rows = table.read_rows(row_set=row_set)
id_values = []
for row in rows:
    # get last id_value from row key
    id_value = str(row.key).replace('phone#20190501#', '')
    id_values.append(id_value)
unique_id_list = list(set(id_values))
print('COUNT: %s' % len(unique_id_list))
```

However, I'm wondering that if I read rows over 100 million, I think this way to calculate unique id_value might eats a lot of memory and cpu.

Is there a better way to count unique ids in Bigtable or function like "UNIQUE" in standard SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bigtable doesn't have a way to sort/unique like SQL, it has to be done on the client side - through code. However, there are some performance considerations that can help you.
You can find it in the below [stack thread posted by DamPlz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67737062/bigtable-aggregation-data):

> 1. In case query speed is a must, [loading the data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data) into BigQuery instead of setting up an external data source would be the most
>    efficient way. Nevertheless, there are some things you can do to
>    improve [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-overview), or [BigTable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/performance) performances.
> 2. This connector is still in the Beta stage, and has some [performance considerations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable#performance_considerations). We should also take into
>    consideration that BigTable is a **noSQL** (non relational) database
>    and is not intended for SQL queries.  In case you are exploring the
>    data model you want to use in your application, I recommend you
>    consider [all these options](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/overview#other-storage-options) and choose the one that fits better
>    with your needs.
> 3. I would say it is not a good choice if you want to query your data using SQL. Understanding de non relational architecture of BigTable,
>    the most effective way to read your data would be sending [read
>    requests](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reads).  You can find some code samples about this, in different
>    languages in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reading-data).

Comment: I will give it a try! Thanks!